# jQuery Load - Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I'm getting the above error when attempting a jquery load:

```
$('#footer').load(UrlOfFooterContent);
```

`UrlOfFooterContent` is the URL of an MVC controller action in a separate website in the same domain.  It would seem that there is a problem dealing with the angle bracket but I don't know how to get around it in this situation.

**Background**

Our website is made up of a number of child websites that each refer to a shared header project.  The header project pushes the header and footer content into empty DIVs in each child website that references it.  The site I'm working on is a little different and doesn't need the header but it does need the footer.

Since the header project pushes the data and I'm not referencing the header, I therefore need the child website to pull the footer content from the header.

This was how it used to work with no problems, `UrlOfFooterContent` used to contain the URL of a text file containing the footer source - however someone changed the header project and now the footer source is only available from the controller action as described above.

Many thanks in advance
Simon

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'separate website on the same domain'? For a basic AJAX request to work the domains must be identical right down to the protocol and port number. Also, it sounds like you would be better to use server side includes rather than using `load()` on the client.

Comment: I'm not sure how do you expect anyone to be able to fix your issue?...

Comment: Have you checked the actual data you're receiving? Use your network tab or an HTTP sniffer.

Comment: It seems `UrlOfFooterContent` is returning error, try console `console.log(UrlOfFooterContent)` and check what it outputs

Comment: When it happens to me it's usually due to an server side error that returns a malformed response

Comment: The domain is the same, it was working well before the parent source changed.  I was thinking I just needed to escape the html but I don't know how to do it in this situation.  UrlOfFooterContent is returning ok - no error.

Comment: Does the footer content contain `<script>` tags, that contain broken JavaScript code?

Comment: Salman - the footer contains some script tags but there are no js errors returned, just the unexpected token one I mentioned.

Comment: @SimonBarnett I think the received html conatins `script`/`script src` which contain errors, or html content served as application/JavaScript. The console should provide a line number and filename. You could use it to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error 'Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' was a red herring - it's related to an internal network issue and will not be see externally.

The correct source was being loaded but there were css files missing also so it bore no resemblance to what I was expecting - all I saw was a mess and an error.

Thanks for your replies.

Oh, A. Wolff - in answer to your question.... check the other replies...